# Undefined class 'Widget'. Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have installed and started my flutter journey but after my first project, all the classes and widgets are showing an error message. It was working at first but I later started getting the error message.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(FirstApp());
}

class FirstApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Code The Best"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Login"),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Register"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I get a number of errors including these:

1. Undefined class 'BuildContext'.
   Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'BuildContext'.

2.Undefined class 'Widget'.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'Widget'.

Comment: Looks like you're missing some `import`s. Did you check to see where Widget and BuildContext are defined?

Answer (score 0):

try removing build folder and re-building it again.
You can do this by,

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get